# Oracle - LISTAGG and ordering fields separated by pipe; order messed up

Tags: oracle, sorting, listagg

There are three fields in one table that need to be parsed; need columns piped together and sorted alphabetically/numerically. When using LISTAGG on the the first column(alphabetic) it sorts them fine, but when using LISTAGG on the other columns, they are also sorted alphabetically/numerically. The issue is these columns( 2 and 3) are no longer bound to the first column, since all columns are sorted individually using LISTAGG per column

I need columns two and three to stay bound to the first columns, but first column must be sorted alphabetically. Columns two and three must follow column one.

Oracle 12g and table data type can not be altered:

```
create table JRNL (
cat       varchar2(25),
cat_type  varchar2(25),
debit     varchar2(15),
credit    varchar2(15)
);

insert into JRNL (CAT_TYPE, CAT, DEBIT, CREDIT) values ('2', 'Car', '800', '5000');
insert into JRNL (CAT_TYPE, CAT, DEBIT, CREDIT) values ('2', 'Trucks', '1700', '1700');
insert into JRNL (CAT_TYPE, CAT, DEBIT, CREDIT) values ('2', 'Motorcycle', '750', '750');
insert into JRNL (CAT_TYPE, CAT, DEBIT, CREDIT) values ('2', 'Bikes', '1500', '1500');
```

SQL below list columns in correct order and values:

```
CAT              Debit             Credit
Bikes            1,500.00          1,500.00
Car              800.00            5,000.00
Motorcycle       750.00            750.00
Trucks           1,700.00          1,700.00
```

Used LISTAGG to pipe fields together, but now fields do not match?

```
SELECT LISTAGG(Cat, '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Cat) Cat,
       LISTAGG(to_char(Debit,'999,999,999,999.99'), '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Debit) Debit,
       LISTAGG(to_char(Credit,'999,999,999,999.99'), '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Credit) Credit
FROM   (
         SELECT Cat, SUM(Debit) Debit, SUM(Credit) Credit
         FROM   jrnl
         WHERE  cat_type = 2
         GROUP BY Cat
       )
ORDER BY Cat
```

Result:

```
CAT                            Debit                             Credit
Bikes|Car|Motorcycle|Trucks    750.00|800.00|1,500.00|1,700.00   750.00|1,500.00|1,700.00|5,000.00
```

notice Debit and Credit values no longer follow values in Cat(i.e. Bike values are 750 and 750 ut teh correct values are 1500 and 1500, as listed in the first output above

Comment: I'm confused... If you're just trying to order your results in the same way, why not just order all your `listagg` statements by the same value? For example, why would your second column have `order by debit` if you want it to be ordered by `cat`?

Comment: `create table JRNL (
cat varchar2 (25),
cat_type varchar2 (25),
debit varchar2 (15),
credit varchar2 (15)
);`

Comment: your right..its Friday!

Comment: how do I accept your answer..where is the fricken ICON

Comment: where is your answer so I can accept

Comment: By the way, `to_char` expressions are a bit risky when the column is already a character type. Probably `debit` and `credit` should be numeric.

Comment: enter a proposed solution so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood what you are saying, all `LISTAGG`s should use the same order by: `cat`

```
  LISTAGG(Cat, '|') WITHIN GROUP                                  (ORDER BY Cat) Cat,
  LISTAGG(to_char(Debit,'999,999,999,999.99'), '|') WITHIN GROUP  (ORDER BY cat) Debit,
  LISTAGG(to_char(Credit,'999,999,999,999.99'), '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cat) Credit
                                                                   ------------
                                                                    This
```